# Cron job syntax debian

Tags: cron, debian

```
33 */27 * * * python /root/get_top.py
```

Would the above snippet run every 27 hours and 33 minutes, or every 27 hours starting at 33 minutes past the hour?

If this doesn't make it run every 27 hours and 33 minutes, what is the proper syntax for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't run, because cron supports these ranges:

```
minutes: 0-59
hours: 0-23
days of month: 1-31
months: 1-12 or Jan-Dec
days of week: 0-6 or Sun-Sat
```

27 for hours is not supported. Anyhow it doesn't exist the 27th hour in a 24-hours day.

Comment: But the slash means "every". So this should be every 27th hour. Just like */4 is "every four hours"

Comment: Slashes describe increments of ranges. For example 3-59/15 in the 1st field (minutes) indicate the third minute of the hour and every 15 minutes thereafter. The form "*/..." is equivalent to the form "first-last/...", that is, an increment over the largest possible range of the field. That's 24 for hours

Comment: The repeating pattern for `27hrs and 33mins` is `2w 6d 15h`.

You should then add many lines to math the 18 items.

But I would prefer to write a wrapper that checks daily if it should be executed that day (i.e. the 27hrs and 33mins period after last execution is going to pass during that day) and schedule it with `at`.

Answer (score 1):

The first field is minutes, so would run at 33 minutes past the hour.

But the next field is the hour field and it is set to run every 27th hour of the day, or in other words, never.

Comment: So how would I get it to run every 27 hours and 33 minutes?

Answer (score 0):

you misunderstand the `/`, it would mean when the number is dividable by that number, for example `*/2` would mean every 2 mins because every 2 mins the number is even and is able to be divided by 2.

When you want to create something specific you need to add it manually comma separated, like for example

```
33 27,54 * * * python /root/get_top.py
```

Comment: 27,54 -- so that cron would only run twice, right? Not every 27 hours

Comment: Exactly, if you want more precise timing maybe think of creating more than one cron line for one command, so the union would create your desired cycle